# Django: No reverse match

Tags: python, django, testing

```
def test_post_request_for_api_view(self):
    data = {
        "email": self.user.email,
    }
    url = self.reverse('users:the_api', self.user.pk)
    response = self.json_post(data, url=url)

    self.mock.assert_called_once_with(self.user)
    data2 = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    self.assertEqual(data2, {
        'booking_order': ['ABCDEFGHIJKL'],
        'transaction_total': '20000.00'
    })
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(
    regex=r'^$',
    view=views.UserListView.as_view(),
    name='list'
),
url(
    regex=r'^~redirect/$',
    view=views.UserRedirectView.as_view(),
    name='redirect'
),
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
    view=views.UserDetailView.as_view(),
    name='detail'
),
url(
    regex=r'^~update/$',
    view=views.UserUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='update'
)    ,
url(
    regex=r'^the_api/$',
    view =  views.UserApiView.as_view(),
    name='the_api'
),
```

]

### views.py

```
class UserApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = authentication.TokenAuthentication ###Am assuming you're authenticating via a token

    def get(self, request):
        """
        Get user based on username.
        Am getting only the username since that's the only field used above.
        :param request:
        :param format:
        :return:
        """
        details = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(details, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data  )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Create a new user instance
        :param request:
        :param format:
        :return:
        """
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

As much as i understand how reverse works in Django, i believe for the above test to pass, i only need to have a ***the_api*** url in my *urls.py*.
However, the test does not pass even with that.
As such, i would love to know what the right thing to do is.
How do i get the test to run?

The error i keep getting is:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'the_api' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users:the_api/$']

Comment: As the error says, your URL is not expecting any arguments but you are passing one (the pk). Why? Does your view need that argument? Maybe you should show the URL and the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have accepted argument in your url? Looking at your code you should have following entry in your urls.py file:

```
url(r'the_api/(\d+)/$', your_view, name="the_api")
```

May be you should paste your url entry too and the corresponding view so that we can look deeper into the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the argument.